# Shopware 6 administration: on create new product, price cannot be null

Tags: shopware6, conceptual

If i create a new product `price.net === null` & `price.gross === null` the product can't be saved.

What is the **concept behind** this? Why can a `product.price` not be `null`?

Answer (score 4):

In the context of a commerce platform a product should have a price, even if it may be `0`. Otherwise every application of a price calculation would have to take into account, that a price might be `null`, which just isn't feasible.

Comment: mmm, i think it is a difference if a product has a price or not. And **it can be a *use case*** in real live: i create a product and publish it. Then i would offer a discussion about the price...maybe as a marketing instrument. It is opposed to a product with price € 0.-

Comment: Well, this `price = null` idea is not really compatible with Shopware, but if you wanted you could just add some custom field like `hidePrice` and add some storefront logic to replace the product's price with a custom message.

Comment: This is a specific use case though which is not at the core of the architecture of the platform and would require the implementation via an extension either way.

Comment: Another point: "...product should have a price, even if it may be 0..." When this is the concept, then the right way could be a default value `0` instead `null`.